# Count all lines from file starting with a certain character and ending with a different character

Tags: c#, winforms, file, text

What I want to achieve is to load a text file and then count all lines that:

1. starting with character "X"
2. Ending with character "Y"

My code looks like this:

```
string txtContent;
try
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        txtContent = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);

    }
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Form1", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

I'm reading txt files contents into `txtContent` string variable. But I have no idea how to continue?

Comment: is it a homework assignment? Please tag it properly then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one liner completely unsuitable for a homework assignment. ;)

```
File.ReadLines(somePath).Count(line=>Regex.IsMatch(line,"(^X.*$)|(^.*Y$)"))
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, let's do "hints" rather than just giving you the code...

- Reading a file in the UI thread is normally a bad idea. It's okay for a quick experiment, but don't do it in production code.
- If you want to read *lines* in a file, use [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) (.NET 2+) or [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503) (.NET 4+)
- Use [`string.StartsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx) and [`string.EndsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith.aspx) to determine whether a string starts or ends in a particular way
- Consider using LINQ's [`Count()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) method to count items matching a predicate

Comment: Not sure if this comment is suitable for SO, just wanted to say I often find myself seeing comments from you on this website and almost always find them extremely helpful.  So I want to say thanks for the help, with not one thing in particular, but just in general. edit: Typing this I just recognised your name and realised I actually have one of your books sat here on my desk... so err thanks for that too I guess... thought it sounded familiar

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like homework, in which case, I'll give you pointers -

If you use [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) (instead of `ReadAllText`), you'll get an array of each line.

You can then use the [methods on String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wtc81z6), such as (`StartsWith` and `EndsWith`) to check your conditions...

Answer (score 0):

Reading all of the text into memory is not very efficient if your goal is to count certain matching lines.  Instead, I would use a buffered stream and process lines one at a time

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.StartsWith(START_CHARACTER) || line.EndsWith(END_CHARACTER))
        { 
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```